# kcfinder blank browse page

Tags: javascript, php, ckeditor, kcfinder

I'm using kcfinder with ckeditor and everything is working perfectly in my local server but after uploading it to my working server i'm getting a blank browse page without any error messages in php or javascript

here is the integration config:

```
filebrowserBrowseUrl: '/~asfor/editor/kcfinder/browse.php?opener=ckeditor&type=files',
filebrowserImageBrowseUrl: '/~asfor/editor/kcfinder/browse.php?opener=ckeditor&type=images',
filebrowserFlashBrowseUrl:'/~asfor/editor/kcfinder/browse.php?opener=ckeditor&type=flash',
filebrowserUploadUrl: '/~asfor/editor/kcfinder/upload.php?opener=ckeditor&type=files',
filebrowserImageUploadUrl: '/~asfor/editor/kcfinder/upload.php?opener=ckeditor&type=images',
filebrowserFlashUploadUrl: '/~asfor/editor/kcfinder/upload.php?opener=ckeditor&type=flash'
```

And here is the basic kcfinder config:

```
'disabled' => false,
'uploadURL' => "upload",
'uploadDir' => "",
'imageDriversPriority' => "gd imagick gmagick",
'denyZipDownload' => true,
'denyUpdateCheck' => true,
'denyExtensionRename' => false,
'dirPerms' => 0755,
'filePerms' => 0644,
```

I can't figure out what's the problem exactly, so can you help me solve it? and thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem on my local linux-machine.

```
sudo chmod -R 0777 kcfinder/upload
```

solved my problem.

Most likely, you can set access rights in your FTP client.